# syntax error at or near "when"

Tags: sql, postgresql

That should be simple.

> "syntax error at or near "when"" error in the 5th line

```
    round(CAST(CASE WHEN x.sprd_units = 0 then 0 ELSE 
        case 
        when sum(case when d.ver_desc_txt = 'BEST OFFICIAL PROJECTION' AND d.veh_desc_txt in ('CORE BROCHURE','CORE BROCHURE ATTACHED','CORE BROCHURE UNATTACHED') 
            THEN d.unit_qty else 0 end) / z.spread_units_cb::numeric
        when sum(case when d.ver_desc_txt = 'BEST OFFICIAL PROJECTION' AND d.veh_desc_txt not in ('CORE BROCHURE','CORE BROCHURE ATTACHED','CORE BROCHURE UNATTACHED') 
            THEN d.unit_qty else 0 end) / x.sprd_units::numeric
        end as numeric) 2) as space_units,
```

Postgresql version is 8.3

I missed something or what? Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, you are missing the `END` to correspond to the first `CASE`

Comment: I think your round statement should have a comma before the 2) as space_units,

Comment: Thanks, you were right. But the issue is more complex

Answer (score 2):

You have a ton of nesting happening here and some parentheticals to boot. The way I deal with messes like this is to indent it like a crazy person. You'll see pretty quickly you are missing some matching THEN clauses to some WHEN clauses and those same WHEN clauses lack a condition. You are just dividing something (not comparing something). Lastly you are missing an END to one of your CASE statements.

```
round(
    CAST(
        CASE 
            WHEN x.sprd_units = 0 
                then 0 
            ELSE 
                case 
                    when sum(
                                case 
                                    when d.ver_desc_txt = 'BEST OFFICIAL PROJECTION' AND d.veh_desc_txt in ('CORE BROCHURE','CORE BROCHURE ATTACHED','CORE BROCHURE UNATTACHED') 
                                        THEN d.unit_qty 
                                    else 0 
                                    end
                            ) / z.spread_units_cb::numeric
                        /*WHEN this is what? there is no condition here, just math*/
                        /*WHERE IS THE THEN ?*/
                    when sum(
                                case 
                                    when d.ver_desc_txt = 'BEST OFFICIAL PROJECTION' AND d.veh_desc_txt not in ('CORE BROCHURE','CORE BROCHURE ATTACHED','CORE BROCHURE UNATTACHED') 
                                        THEN d.unit_qty 
                                    else 0 
                                    end
                            ) / x.sprd_units::numeric
                        /*WHEN this is what? there is no condition here, just math*/
                        /*AGAIN NO THEN*/
                    /*THIS CASE IS MISSING AN END*/
        end as numeric
    ), 2
) as space_units,
```

Comment: Also, do you need to do that cast? Is there any route through this nested case that won't result in a number? Perhaps there is, which is fine, but I would consider removing it once you get the logic worked out since it will just add unnecessary CPU (not much, but these little insignificant things can really add up when done across millions of records).

Comment: hmm, I will explain more. This code is about to compute "space_units". Differently depends on "veh_desc_txt". For vehicles 'CORE BROCHURE','CORE BROCHURE ATTACHED','CORE BROCHURE UNATTACHED' i would like to have: d.unit_qty / z.spread_units_cb. For rest of vehicles I would like to have d.unit_qty  / x.sprd_units. For rest of cases (ver_desc_txt is not BEST OFFICIAL PROJECTION) I want to show blanks. Is this helpful?

Answer (score 1):

All this nesting is unneeded.  `CASE` supports multiple conditions.  You are missing two `CASE` conditions (marked below with `?`), but I assume the second is an `ELSE`.  You are also missing the comma before the "2":

```
round(cast(case when x.sprd_units = 0 then 0 
                when ?
                then sum(case when d.ver_desc_txt = 'BEST OFFICIAL PROJECTION' AND d.veh_desc_txt in ('CORE BROCHURE', 'CORE BROCHURE ATTACHED', 'CORE BROCHURE UNATTACHED') 
                              then d.unit_qty
                              else 0
                         end) / z.spread_units_cb::numeric
                else sum(case when d.ver_desc_txt = 'BEST OFFICIAL PROJECTION' AND d.veh_desc_txt not in ('CORE BROCHURE', 'CORE BROCHURE ATTACHED', 'CORE BROCHURE UNATTACHED') 
                              then d.unit_qty else 0
                         end) / x.sprd_units::numeric
           end as numeric), 2) as space_units,
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I will reply answer to JNevill above: hmm, I will explain more. This code is about to compute "space_units". Differently depends on "veh_desc_txt". For vehicles 'CORE BROCHURE','CORE BROCHURE ATTACHED','CORE BROCHURE UNATTACHED' i would like to have: d.unit_qty / z.spread_units_cb. For rest of vehicles I would like to have d.unit_qty / x.sprd_units. For rest of cases (ver_desc_txt is not BEST OFFICIAL PROJECTION) I want to show blanks.

Comment: Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I finally made it:

```
round(CAST(sum(d.unit_qty / case 
                                    when d.veh_desc_txt in ('CORE BROCHURE','CORE BROCHURE ATTACHED','CORE BROCHURE UNATTACHED') and d.ver_desc_txt = 'BEST OFFICIAL PROJECTION'
                                        then nullif(z.spread_units_cb, 0)::numeric
                                    when d.veh_desc_txt not in ('CORE BROCHURE','CORE BROCHURE ATTACHED','CORE BROCHURE UNATTACHED') and d.ver_desc_txt = 'BEST OFFICIAL PROJECTION'
                                        then nullif(x.sprd_units, 0)::numeric

                                    end)
            as numeric),                        
        2) as space_units,
```